# "Mouse Middle Click" paste to exactly where mousecursor is

Tags: 18.04, mouse

**[Edit]**: *The observed problem was misleading, as it turned out to be rooted in Google Doc's behaviour. Please see accepted answer.*

Is it possible to configure the "middle mouse click"-paste option to paste text not where the text cursor is, but rather where the mouse cursor is?

**What happens:**
To be more specific, if I select a text, mouse-over another part of the document and middle-click, the text is pasted "over the selection", meaning I overwrite the selected text with the pasted text (ergo, not much happens). For pasting the text where I am pointing, I first have to left-click to move the text cursor to this location, afterwards I can paste the selection.

**What I want to happen:** If I remember correctly, there was a time or configuration that allowed me to paste the text just where my mouse cursor pointed, allowing me to select a text, mouse-over a different text part and paste it just by middle-clicking. It was essentially like a simulated left-click prior to the middle click.

Comment: you must not be using ubuntu because my text gets pasted wherever I have my pointer not where selection or text cursor is. even in libre office.

Comment: @tatsu Same here. In fact, middle click pastes the selected text, *not* the text in the clipboard. Never noticed that.

Comment: yeah that was always the case, it's a seperate clipboard on purpose, it's more powerfull that way. (you can juggle between things you put in one or the other and at what time you choose to paste one or the other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments made me aware that apparently the Google Docs webpage seems to be the problem. In fact, Gedit, LibreOffice, (as well as this answer I am typing) and other tools function properly.

If this problem occurs for others, check other applications first. Thanks to the commenters!